# Convert "29apr1988" to Date format e.g 1988-04-29

Tags: r, date, datetime

Can you suggest an elegant way to convert this string into the standard Date format? Thanks

Comment: Simply read the first example in the help page of `?as.Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format.Date` has many available date formats

```
dat <- "29apr1988"
as.Date(dat, format="%d%b%Y")
# [1] "1988-04-29"
```

Answer (score 1):

`lubridate` package takes out the need to understand the formating in base `format.Date`

```
require(lubridate)
dmy("29apr1988")
# [1] "1988-04-29 UTC"
```